# MongoError: Invalid Operation, No operations in bulk for insertion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules, node-mongodb-native

Below is my code for bulk insertion.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    "xyz": String
}, {
    collection: 'user'
});

Api.prototype.Users = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);

resultData = [{
    "xyz": "abc"
}, {
    "xyz": "44545"
}, {
    "xyz": "545"
}]

Api.prototype.Users.collection.insert(resultData, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("User inserted : " + data.result.n);
    }
});
```

But i'm getting this error: MongoError: Invalid Operation, No operations in      bulk

> MongoError: Invalid Operation, No operations in bulk
>       at Function.MongoError.create (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
>       at toError (/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:114:22)

Comment: what the version on mongo driver you are using..?

Comment: i'm also facing same issues

Comment: @williams you have defined field as abc and inserted as xyz

Comment: sorry,i've edited now.thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the Mongoose `Users.create` instead of the native `Users.collection.insert`?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error when trying to bulk insert an empty array using insertMany. You should check for an empty array before attempting a bulk insert.

```
if (resultData.length > 0) {
  // do bulk insert...
}
```